# listview selected item error

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, thread-safety

I have a listview in another thread, i add items to it in safe thread-safe manner, like this:

`listView1.Invoke(new AddTolstDiscoveredDevices(AddDiscoveryEntry), ReceiveString);`

but when i tried to get a selected items, it say the index `0` is invalid.

i used this:

`string IpAdr = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;`

error = `"InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.\r\nParameter name: index"`

then since it is on another thread, i tried to invoke like this:

```
 public string GetCurrentItem(int location)
    {
        if (this.listView1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            getCurrentItemCallBack d = new getCurrentItemCallBack(GetCurrentItem);
            return this.Invoke(d, new object[] { location }).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return this.listView1.Items[location].Text;
        }
    }
```

when i call, i got the same error.

i can't understand what is wrong.

any help is appreciated. thx.

Comment: have you checked listView1 count and that it's not null?

Comment: @DarthVader, yes. ` if (this.listView1.SelectedItems.Count != null) { string IpAdress = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text; }` it say the value of `1` is not valid for `index`

Comment: i found the problem. as long as i am inside the tab which the listview contains i get extract items from the listview. i guess i need to rearrange my gui design. i dont know why it can't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use ListView.SelectedIndices Property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindices.aspx

```
if (this.listView1.SelectedIndices.Count > 0) 
{ 
     string IpAdress = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]].Text; 
}
```